# Google OAuth2 Grant Limits

Tags: google-oauth

Is there a maximum amount of oauth2 grants you can have from 1 Google account to 1 client_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but new grants are only added on explicit user consent options. Auto-approved events don't increase the number of grants, so there is no limit on the outstanding number of tokens.

The maximum number of grants per client_id/user is 25 at this time, and we're working to raise it.